# react-native Android Module open PassWallet

Tags: android, react-native

I want to save a .pkpass WalletPass in my react-native app. I made a Module with information from this developer guide: http://passwallet.attidomobile.com/PassWallet%20Developer%20Guide.pdf my module looks like the following:

PassWallet.java:

```
package mypackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class PassWallet extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public PassWallet(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "PassWallet";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void saveToPassWallet(String url) {
        launchPassWallet(getReactApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url), true);
    }

    private boolean launchPassWallet(Context applicationContext, Uri uri, boolean launchGooglePlay) {

        if (null != applicationContext) {

            PackageManager packageManager = applicationContext.getPackageManager();

            if (null != packageManager) {

                final String strPackageName = "com.attidomobile.passwallet";

                Intent startIntent = new Intent();
                startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                Intent passWalletLaunchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(strPackageName);
                if (null == passWalletLaunchIntent) {

                    // PassWallet isn't installed, open Google Play:
                    if (launchGooglePlay) {

                        String strReferrer = "";
                        try {
                            final String strEncodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(uri.toString(), "UTF-8");
                            strReferrer = "&referrer=" + strEncodedURL;
                        }
                        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            strReferrer = "";
                        }
                        try {
                            startIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + strPackageName + strReferrer));
                            applicationContext.startActivity(startIntent);
                        }
                        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            // Google Play not installed, open via website
                            startIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + strPackageName + strReferrer));
                            applicationContext.startActivity(startIntent);
                        }

                    }


                }
                else {

                    final String strClassName = "com.attidomobile.passwallet.activity.TicketDetailActivity";

                    startIntent.setClassName(strPackageName, strClassName);
                    startIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                    startIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.apple.pkpass");

                    applicationContext.startActivity(startIntent);

                    return true;

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I added the module correctly and can open it in my react-native javascript files:

```
const AndroidWalletManager = NativeModules.PassWallet;
...

AndroidWalletManager.saveToPassWallet(url);
...
```

When I open a .pkpass file and the Wallet App (PassWallet, like the link to the developer guide) is not installed, the Play store opens correctly. But when the app is installed the following error is shown:

[image]

I'm not a android developer so maybe this is a basic problem, but I don't know how to solve this. If I had to guess I would say the PassWallet App changed the activity name, is this correct? I had this solution for like two years and it worked in the past. I contacted the author of this developer guide but didn't get a response so far. Is there a better way to do this?

I just want to be able to save a .pkpass directly to a Wallet App on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity name was changed after a major release 2.00.XX
Please find the latest instructions here: https://github.com/Kwiket/passwallet

Passwallet Team